# Problem while creating the 95proxies file

Tags: 14.04, command-line, proxy, gedit

When I run this command in Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

The following message is displayed:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d is directory
please check that you typed the location correctly and try again
```

Please help in resolving this to create 95 proxies file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` path.

Answer (score 0):

Give the filename as well:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

And please [do not use `sudo` with graphical programs directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application/270019#270019). Use `gksudo`, or `sudo -H`.